# Compare columns from two different dataframes pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am querying AD for a list of machines. I filter this list with pandas by last log on date. When I am done with this data I have one column in 
a dataframe.

I have another report that has a list of machines that a product we use is installed. I clean this data and I am left with the devices that I want to use to compare to the AD data. Which is just one column in a dataframe.

I have also tried comparing list to list. I am not sure on the best the method.

I tried the merge but my guess this compares DF1 row 1 to DF2 row 1.

```
DF1 = comp1,comp2,comp3,comp5

DF2 = comp1,comp2,comp3
```

How would I check each row in DF1 to make sure that each value in DF2 exist and return true or false?

I am trying to figure out machines in DF1 that don't exist in DF2.

Answer (score 0):

## [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

this is a simple check to see if one value is in another, you do this in a multitude of ways, this is probably one of the simpliest.

I'm providing some dummy data but please check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

```
machines = ['A','B','C']
machines_to_check = ['A','B']

df = pd.DataFrame({'AD' : machines})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AD' : machines_to_check})
```

now, if we want to check for the machines that exist in df but not in df2 we can use `~` which inverts the `.isin` function.

```
non_matching_machines = df.loc[~df['AD'].isin(df2['AD'])]
print(non_matching_machines)
    AD
2   C
```